# Get outerHTML from an HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I already know that we can get outerHTML if the element can access direly like

```
    var htmlString = $('#mySelectBox').outerHTML;
```

What if the element can't access directly because it is generated from a framework like ASP Entity Framework and we do not have direct access to that element but to one of its grand parents, like

```
    $('#table-body:first-child').closest('select').children;
```

This **children** property returns an HTMLCollection and is there a way to get outerHTML of each child of that HTMLCollection.

```
    var optionsHTMLCollection = $('#table-body:first-child').closest('select').children;
```

I tried this, but failed.

```
    var optionsAsHTMLString = '';
    for (var i=0; i<optionsHTMLCollection.length; I++) {
       optionsAsHTMLString 
    }
```

**Update 1**(Because @Twisty is asking for more HTML in the comments below. I'm pasting as it is. Later I will minimize more)

```
<table class="table table-dark table-hover">
    <thead class="align-middle">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Seq No</th>
            <th scope="col">Item Category</th>
            <th scope="col">Percentage (%)</th>
            <th scope="col">Item Name</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>
                <select class="form-select"
                    data-val="true" data-val-required="The ItemCatId field is required."
                    id="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList_0__ItemCatId" name="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList[0].ItemCatId">
                    <option selected>-- select product finishing type --</option>
                    <option value="1">HIGH DENSITY POLYETHYLENE</option>
                    <option value="2">LINEAR LOW DENSITY POLYETHYLENE</option>
                </select>
                <b><span class="text-danger" for=""></span></b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Percentage" data-val="true"
                    data-val-number="The field Percentage must be a number."
                    data-val-range="Percentage is between 0% and 100%" data-val-range-max="100" data-val-range-min="0"
                    data-val-required="The Percentage field is required." id="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList_0__Percentage"
                    name="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList[0].Percentage" value="">
                <b><span class="text-danger" for="BagType.Isactive"></span></b>
            </td>
            <td class="align-bottom">
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger rounded del-this-row"><i
                            class="fa-regular fa-trash-can"></i> Delete</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>
                <select class="form-select" 
                    data-val="true" data-val-required="The ItemCatId field is required."
                    id="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList_1__ItemCatId" name="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList[1].ItemCatId">
                    <option selected>-- select product finishing type --</option>
                    <option value="1">HIGH DENSITY POLYETHYLENE</option>
                    <option value="2">LINEAR LOW DENSITY POLYETHYLENE</option>
                </select>
                <b><span class="text-danger" for=""></span></b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Percentage" data-val="true"
                    data-val-number="The field Percentage must be a number."
                    data-val-range="Percentage is between 0% and 100%" data-val-range-max="100" data-val-range-min="0"
                    data-val-required="The Percentage field is required." id="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList_1__Percentage"
                    name="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList[1].Percentage" value="">
                <b><span class="text-danger" for="BagType.Isactive"></span></b>
            </td>
            <td class="align-bottom">
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger rounded del-this-row"><i
                            class="fa-regular fa-trash-can"></i> Delete</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td class="border-0" colspan="4" style="text-align: right;">
                Need To Add New Row?
            </td>
            <td class="border-0">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <button id="add-row" type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-circle">+</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I want to target the first select box which is in the first row and to get its all option childrens to a string variable with all the markup to concatenate into a html template mentioned below. All the Ids, name=, ... are generated by ASP MVC. That is why is looks complex.

HTML TEMPLATE

```
                   `<tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-select" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ItemCatId field is required." id="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList_`+ row_count +`__ItemCatId" name="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList[` + row_count + `].ItemCatId">
                                `
                                + select_items_list +
                                `
                            </select>
                            <b><span class="text-danger" for=""></span></b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Percentage" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Percentage must be a number." data-val-range="Percentage is between 0% and 100%" data-val-range-max="100" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="The Percentage field is required." id="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList_`+ row_count + `__Percentage" name="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList[` + row_count + `].Percentage" value="">
                            <b><span class="text-danger" for="BagType.Isactive"></span></b>
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-bottom">
                            <div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger rounded del-this-row"><i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can"></i> Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>`
```

Here row_count, select_items_list are string variables

Comment: jQuery does not have an outerHTML or children property so unsure how those lines would work.

Comment: So loop over the collection and read the outerHTML of the elements and push that to an array or append it to a string. We are unsure what the expected outcome is supposed to be.

Comment: The output will be a string like "<option>one</option><option>two</option>..."

Comment: It's not clear why you are mixing jQuery and JavaScript. It might be best to strictly use one or the other. For example, `$("#mySelectBox").prop("outerHTML")` to get the Outer HTML String of the Object.

Comment: Also, ASP is a Server Side Script, so it would execute before the result is sent to the web browser. So all the HTML should be available to the client side script.

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is adding additional select box from a button using java script or query because user can add as many items(select boxes) he want to add to the html table. So there was no way found to do it from the server side.

Comment: @LakshithaKanchana Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty it is more complex, the original code which I was implementing locally. I dropped here is a fragment. I find it impossible to minimize further. If you wish I will drop the whole code so that you can help with.

Comment: I may be missing something but do not understand why this is a problem. Provided the element is already rendered on the page, you have access to it through JS, regardless of how it was made. Target the `select` item (by position, className, ID or other identifier) and append a newly created `option` element to it with the required `value` and `innerHTML`.  Sorry if I've missed something.

Comment: @LakshithaKanchana your examples do not show any HTML so there is no way to understand the relationship that the jQuery is trying to use. this makes it almost impossible for people to help further. You may want to use a jsfiddle or a snippet to provide a more clear example. As it is, there are many comments that point out various syntax issues in what you have presented.

Comment: @Dave thanks for your idea, but here I have to do is copying all <option> elements from rendered page select box and pasting(concatenating) into a new select box template which I have not added to the page still. Because it is a template, I think it is best to add option tags before adding back to the page.

Comment: @Twisty I will put more html under update 1

Comment: @LakshithaKanchana there are more concerns and issues. Firstly, `.closest()` climbs the hierarchy and you don't want to use that here. You should use `.find()` instead. Secondly, it's not clear what you want to do with each of the Options. If you just want the HTML of each, that is pretty easy. It's not clear where you want that to go or what should happen with that text. Please clarify. This almost sounds like you;re asking X trying to solve for Y.

Comment: I need some break. I'll continue later.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".table .form-select").each(function(i, sel) {
    console.log($(sel).attr("id"));
    $("option", sel).each(function(j, el) {
      console.log($(el).prop("outerHTML"));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-dark table-hover">
  <thead class="align-middle">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Seq No</th>
      <th scope="col">Item Category</th>
      <th scope="col">Percentage (%)</th>
      <th scope="col">Item Name</th>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>
        <select class="form-select" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ItemCatId field is required." id="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList_0__ItemCatId" name="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList[0].ItemCatId">
          <option selected>-- select product finishing type --</option>
          <option value="1">HIGH DENSITY POLYETHYLENE</option>
          <option value="2">LINEAR LOW DENSITY POLYETHYLENE</option>
        </select>
        <b><span class="text-danger" for=""></span></b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Percentage" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Percentage must be a number." data-val-range="Percentage is between 0% and 100%" data-val-range-max="100" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="The Percentage field is required."
          id="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList_0__Percentage" name="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList[0].Percentage" value="">
        <b><span class="text-danger" for="BagType.Isactive"></span></b>
      </td>
      <td class="align-bottom">
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger rounded del-this-row"><i
                            class="fa-regular fa-trash-can"></i> Delete</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>
        <select class="form-select" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ItemCatId field is required." id="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList_1__ItemCatId" name="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList[1].ItemCatId">
          <option selected>-- select product finishing type --</option>
          <option value="1">HIGH DENSITY POLYETHYLENE</option>
          <option value="2">LINEAR LOW DENSITY POLYETHYLENE</option>
        </select>
        <b><span class="text-danger" for=""></span></b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Percentage" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Percentage must be a number." data-val-range="Percentage is between 0% and 100%" data-val-range-max="100" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="The Percentage field is required."
          id="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList_1__Percentage" name="PolyCombItemCatBridgeList[1].Percentage" value="">
        <b><span class="text-danger" for="BagType.Isactive"></span></b>
      </td>
      <td class="align-bottom">
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger rounded del-this-row"><i
                            class="fa-regular fa-trash-can"></i> Delete</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td class="border-0" colspan="4" style="text-align: right;">
        Need To Add New Row?
      </td>
      <td class="border-0">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
          <button id="add-row" type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-circle">+</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

As you can see, this uses the Selector to find the `select` element. It then uses Each to iterate each element of that selector. I perform another loop of all child `option` elements of that `select` to gather the HTML for each.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @epascarello, I understood the problem. **I was mixing jQuery with JavaScript**. Using only the **[jQuery Traversing Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_traversing.asp)** was solved the problem. As the following.

```
var optionsHTMLCollection = $('#table-body').find('select').prop('innerHTML');
```

For update 1

```
var select_items_list = $('#table-body').find('select').prop('innerHTML'); // As per the update 1
```